# Queue AJAX requests in react/redux

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, queue, react-redux

I have a set of tasks that needs to be executed *in order* on server side. The problem is I cant seem to figure out how to implement a queue without cluttering the store.

I thought best solution might be to encapsulate it all in a class, and just use a single action  something like `SET_QUEUE(queue)` to keep it up to date. But then that does not play well with the react engine - objects are stripped from methods.

Possible solution might be to put some serialize/deserialize functionality in the class. But im afraid there will be loose ends if requests fire off before state is synced?

Below is a draft of one of my attempts.

```
export default class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.waiting = [];
        this.finished = [];
        this.processingNow = null;

    }

    register(items) {
        this.waiting = items;
    }

    process() {
        if(!this.isBusy() && this.hasWaitingItems()) {
            this.processItem(this.waiting.shift());
        }
    }

    hasWaitingItems() {
        return this.waiting.length > 0;
    }

    isBusy() {
        return this.processingNow == null;
    }

    processItem(item) {
        this.processingNow = item;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/perform/" + item.data.name,
            data: {
                data: JSON.stringify(item.data)
            },
            success: function(result){
                this.processingNow = null;    
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(error) {
                ....
                this.processingNow = null;
                this.waiting = [];
            }.bind(this)
        });        
    }
}
```

In the parent - a component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(!_.isEqual(this.props.queue, nextProps.queue)) {
        nextProps.queue.process();
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Is there a best practice for handling queues / consecutive ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem but in my current project I also had a similar problem where a batch of AJAX requests needed to be sent in a specific order to our REST API. I ended up using Redux Observables https://redux-observable.js.org which is an RxJS middleware for Redux. It allowed me to listen to certain redux actions and react on them with another action launching consecutive AJAX requests.

If you are not already familiar with RxJS it might take a while to learn and understand how it really works but in my opinion it is worth the trouble. For me it has become an important tool to use in various situations.